What is it called when when a data series is multiplied by minus 1?
I have a data series as shown below

It appears that the reference is off.  The troughs should be peaks.
For example, assume V1 = 8mV and V2 = 13mV
I should be seeing graph point =  V2 - V1 = 5mV but instead I am seeing V1 - V2 = -5mV.
I will multiple all values by -1 to get corrected values.  Is there a mathematical name for the operation of changing signs?

"changing signs"

"Invert the $y$-axis"
I might say you have the polarity reversed because you plugged in the $+$ and $-$ wires backwards.

Invert and inverse are overloaded words, which could mean reversing a function or taking the reciprocal (the multiplicative inverse) or even as in your suggestion multiplying  by $-1$ (the additive inverse).

I'll stand by my answer. I think "Invert the y-axis" will be quite clear if OP says why it was done.

@MJD seems invert the y-axis may have an alterante meaning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051744/how-to-invert-the-x-or-y-axis  Is there any refeence that point to invert the y-axis as having the meaning you postulate?

That post is using the term the same way I am.
